# Getting error when trying to scan into an int64 pointer in Go

Tags: go

I'm getting this error

```
 Scan error on column index 1: converting string "<nil>" to a int64:
 strconv.ParseInt: parsing "<nil>": invalid syntax
```

when trying to run this simple code:

```
var id int64
var replyTo *int64
replyTo = new(int64)

query := `
    SELECT id, reply_to
    FROM message
    WHERE id = 211
    LIMIT 1;
`
if err := sql.DB.QueryRow(query).Scan(&id, replyTo); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

spew.Dump(id, replyTo)
```

The table I am selecting from looks like this:

[image]

If I change the select query to: `WHERE id = 210`, instead of 211 then it works.

The sql.DB is just an instance of the sqlx library.

```
var DB *sqlx.DB
```

I am using a pointer to be able to catch NULL columns from the database. I am using a pointer because I am not sure if sql.NullInt64 works well with the sqlx library.

Why do I get this error? What can I do about it?

Comment: To write null to a pointer you need to pass pointer to pointer to a function. I am not sure if it will work with Scan though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scan` needs a pointer to your pointer for this to work  :

```
var id int64
var replyTo *int64
replyTo = new(int64)

query := `
    SELECT id, reply_to
    FROM message
    WHERE id = 211
    LIMIT 1;
`
// The change is here : &replyTo instead of just replyTo
if err := sql.DB.QueryRow(query).Scan(&id, &replyTo); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

spew.Dump(id, replyTo)
```

Then don't forget to test for `replyTo == nil` before using the value `*replyTo`

Alternative solution : use a `sql.NullInt64` : https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64